# Excel VBA: How to read Column data and delete Worksheet based on criteria

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, worksheet-function, worksheet, vba

I have done an extensive amount of research on this topic but no luck so far. 
I have moderate experience with programming.

That said my issue is in regards to reading data from a column and deleting the worksheet if certain text is read 47 times.

In Column "***L***" text ("***n/m***") is repeated 47x times. Text always begins in row 14 and always goes on until row 70. Within that range there are ***spaces*** and 
***"--------"***

***If*** that column has 47 "***n/m***" then the worksheet can be deleted and it has to be applied/repeated for the whole workbook which contained around 40 to 100 worksheets.

My code:

First try didn't work

```
Sub DeletingBlankPages()
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim nm As Range

Set nm = Ws.Range(Columns("12"))
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
nm.Select

If nm Is "n/m" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Ws.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
Next Ws
End Sub
```

Second try still didnt work

```
Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria()
Dim Ws As Worksheet
For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

If Range(Columns("12")).Value < 47 > "n/m" _
Then _
    Ws.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

Next Ws
End Sub
```

If any of you with experience know how to solve this please respond.
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean that if "n/m" is found in 47 or more cells in column L you want to delete the sheet? Will the cells contain text other than "n/m"? I would have thought you could use COUNTIF function in VBA.

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, try this

```
Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria()

Dim i As Long

For i = Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets(i).Range("L14:L70"), "n/m") >= 47 Then
        If Sheets.Count > 1 Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Sheets(i).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Else
            MsgBox "Only 1 sheet left"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: not to be picky but would not `Worksheets` be better than `Sheets`?

Comment: Scott - you are right, I am naturally lazy and saved myself some typing.

Comment: Thank you SJR, this was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria()
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Counter As Integer

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  Counter = 0
  For i = 14 To 70
      If Ws.Cells(i, 12) = "n/m" Then
          Counter = Counter + 1
      End If
  Next i
  If Counter >= 47 Then
      Ws.Delete
  End If
Next Ws
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub